# Universal Windows App in Visual Studio 2015 missing multiple references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2015, cortana

Hi guys and merry christmas!

For my granddad struggling with file movements on his Windows 10 notebook I currently work on a Windows App that gets launched by Cortana and is meant to either move files from one directory to another or to simply open the Windows Explorer.

Therefore I have a project based on [this footage, from a custom cortana commands tutorial](https://github.com/crclayton/custom-cortana-commands-template/blob/master/CustomCortanaCommands/App.xaml.cs).

I tested the App without trying to make Cortana archieve anything rather than responding to a command which worked out just fine.

But going further, I tried to implement the file movements stated above. One try was the following

```
    using System.Diagnostics;
    ...
    private void startprocess()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd");
    }
```

which fails ("'Process' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics') although every reference one could probably state is stated in the beginning of App.xaml.cs.

Trying something like

```
switch (commandName)
            {
                case "filecopy":

                    dialog.Content = "Opening file";
                    await dialog.ShowAsync();

                    string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Public\test\Textdatei vom testordner.txt";
                    string destinationFile = "C:\Users\Public\private\Textdatei vom testordner.txt";

                    File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                    dialog.Content = "Moving files completed";
                    await dialog.ShowAsync();
                    break;
             }
```

with beging inside a lager 'protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)' makes the first dialog come up but that's all. The app closes itself after dismissing the dialog and no file is copied.

Other file movement possibilities found on the net for C# of course also do not work due to VS2015 not knowing the stated references.

After spending hours on Google & Stackoverflow I recognized this might be due to .NET Framework 5.0 and 4.6. I just upgraded the project to the new 5.0.1 beta after having tried out 4.6 and even reinstalling the NuGet packages like Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform.

All solutions to this even lead to more errors in Visual Studio and don't seem to solve the problem that VS2015 does not support many basic C# commands/ functions making it unbelievably hard to use it for programming (unfortunately Universal Windows Apps don't seem to run using Python code).

So I beg anyone having had this seemingly exceptional problem him-/herself or anyone having any clue what to do, please give me a hint :-)
Thanks to all in advance and enjoy the holidays!

Comment: I think what you are looking at can not be achieved with Windows RT.

Comment: So simple file movements are not possible in C# Code inside a Windows App? :O

Comment: In a Universal Windows app, no. But you can still create a classic windows (eg, WPF) app to do whatever you need, and have access to any part of the system. You just won't be able to distribute it via the Windows Store, but given that this is an app for a specific person, that doesn't sound like much of a limitation.

Comment: And it can be still called by Cortana to function in the foreground or background? This would solve it :)